# Java replaceAll - regex variable not replaced

Tags: java

I have one variable representing the regex, when run replaceAll, none of string is replaced. Please help to take a look.

```
String s = "Issue 3 for 5 describe the title";
String regex = "Issue\\s\\d+\\sfor\\s\\d+";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regex, "test"));
```

Comment: "test describe the title" is the output, which is correct apparently. What is the problem?

Comment: Hi FUVM, yes it gives the correct output for above code. I forgot to mention that the regex variable value is derived from XML file: <regex>Issue\\s\\d+\\sfor\\s\\d+</regex>. When i parse the XML and give the value to variable regex, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` returns the modified `String`, but it does not modify the original `String`, as `String` in Java is immutable.

You need to:

```
String resultString = s.replaceAll(regex, "test")
System.out.println(resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java String is immutable.
If you want to change string `s` use this:

`s = s.replaceAll(regex, "test"));`

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the fact that in your code you have to double escape your regexp, but in the xml you don't:

```
String regex = "Issue\\s\\d+\\sfor\\s\\d+";
```

is equivalent to the parsed

```
<regex>Issue\s\d+\sfor\s\d+</regex>
```